# Find column and row of relative approximate value

Tags: google-sheets

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHClX.png)

I want to lookup the table on the left, by using the one on the right. I want to get approximate values to the ones on the right, like the yellow ones I inputed manually. Example: the one on the right has 1.34, which corresponds to 1.33 to the one on the left, but I wanna get its position as it's in column 1, line 5. I've been banging my mind over this for the past 5 hours, plus english isn't my native language, so I'm sorry if I can't write a very articulate question.

I tried the following code:

```
=arrayformula(ABS(H3-C3:E10)=MIN(ABS(C3:E10-H3)))
```

resulting in this matrix:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfVgf.png)

Comment: How do you deal with the value of 1,61 in the table on the right? It is equally close to both 1,60 & 1,62 in the lookup table so could give a result of 1:6 (as shown) or 2:4...

Comment: @TheGodofBiscuits hadn't noticed this, but either one would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This formula will return the indices of multiple positions in the lookup table if multiple values are equally close to the input value - that seems to be the fairest way of dealing with this situation:

```
=arrayformula(let(
lookuptable,A1:C8,
positionmatrix,to_text(sequence(1,columns(lookuptable))&":"&sequence(rows(lookuptable))),
map(E1:I3,lambda(each,join(",",tocol(if(abs(each-lookuptable)=min(abs(each-lookuptable)),positionmatrix,),1))))))
```